# Apache Directory LDAP API - getting up and running

Tags: ldap, apacheds, apache-directory

When I try and run a test using the Apache LDAP API, I am getting the following error. I set up a Maven project , and my pom.xml has many dependencies for the Apache Directory server and API artifacts. My code (which I copied and pasted an example, just to get up and running, so that I can explore) all builds fine. However, when I run it (as a Junit Test), I get the following....

Can anyone help me? maybe even just provide an example of where the Apache LDAP API is being used successfully, and maybe give me the pom.xml with the correct dependencies also? (The apche LDAP API documentation seems to be out of date).

I am currently starting the test using the embedded Apache Directory server, using the following...

```
@RunWith(FrameworkRunner.class)
@CreateLdapServer(transports =
    {
        @CreateTransport(protocol = "LDAP") ,
        @CreateTransport(protocol = "LDAPS") })
// disable changelog, for more info see DIRSERVER-1528
@CreateDS(enableChangeLog = false, name = "PasswordPolicyTest")
public class PasswordPolicyIT extends AbstractLdapTestUnit
{ .......etc }
```

So, therefore, an alternative approach, is that if I tailor some of the tests to just connect to a local Directory Server instance that I have running on my machine. I assume that this would stop the error messages that I am getting below..Again, if anyone could provide a code snippet there, it would be useful..

Many Thanks

```
> 2013-06-20 16:05:10 ERROR FrameworkRunner:287 - Problem locating LDIF
> file in schema repository Multiple copies of resource named
> 'schema/ou=schema/cn=apachemeta/ou=matchingrules/m-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.0.1.3.ldif'
> located on classpath at urls
>     jar:file:/Users/rk/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-ldap-client-all/1.0.0-M17/api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M17.jar!/schema/ou%3dschema/cn%3dapachemeta/ou%3dmatchingrules/m-oid%3d1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.0.1.3.ldif
>     jar:file:/Users/rk/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/shared/shared-ldap-schema-data/1.0.0-M7/shared-ldap-schema-data-1.0.0-M7.jar!/schema/ou%3dschema/cn%3dapachemeta/ou%3dmatchingrules/m-oid%3d1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.0.1.3.ldif
>     jar:file:/Users/rk/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-all/2.0.0-M12/apacheds-all-2.0.0-M12.jar!/schema/ou%3dschema/cn%3dapachemeta/ou%3dmatchingrules/m-oid%3d1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.0.1.3.ldif
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the shared-ldap-schema-data dependency from apacheds-all. Take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151758/apache-ds-ads-pwdexpirewarning-not-working-supported/17162454#17162454)

Comment: Tried this still not working. Have put the details in the other comment, when you click on the comment above..

Comment: Can you please just copy in or send the pom.xml file, so we have all of the correct dependencies to get the test code that you sent up and working. The documentation on the apache page, seems way out of date. I would really like to get this API up and running to see if we can utilize it to carry put our particular requirements.

Comment: Remove org.apache.directory.api:api-all, leave only org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-all .